# LinkButton event is not firing with bootstrap data-toggle

Tags: asp.net, events, postback, linkbutton

I have a menu in my asp page composed from linkbuttons. I am using a div container and an unorder list. Every list item is a linkbutton. My problem is that when i click a linkbutton it is not doing postback.

My asp code:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Companies.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Shareholder.aspx.cs" Inherits="GAD.Shareholder" Title="Untitled Page" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/ShareholderListControl.ascx" TagPrefix="gad" TagName="ShareholderListControl" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/ShareholderEditControl.ascx" TagPrefix="gad" TagName="ShareholderEditControl" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/CapitalSubscriptionListControl.ascx" TagPrefix="gad" TagName="CapitalSubscriptionListControl" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/CapitalSubscriptionEditControl.ascx" TagPrefix="gad" TagName="CapitalSubscriptionEditControl" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/ShareholderCollectListControl.ascx" TagPrefix="gad" TagName="ShareholderCollectListControl" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/ShareholderCollectEditControl.ascx" TagPrefix="gad" TagName="ShareholderCollectEditControl" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/ShareholderExpenditureListControl.ascx" TagPrefix="gad" TagName="ShareholderExpenditureListControl" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/ShareholderExpenditureEditControl.ascx" TagPrefix="gad" TagName="ShareholderExpenditureEditControl" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/ShareholderPayoutListControl.ascx" TagPrefix="gad" TagName="ShareholderPayoutListControl" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/ShareholderPayoutEditControl.ascx" TagPrefix="gad" TagName="ShareholderPayoutEditControl" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/DocumentListControl.ascx" TagPrefix="gad" TagName="DocumentListControl" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/DocumentEditControl.ascx" TagPrefix="gad" TagName="DocumentEditControl" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/AlertListControl.ascx" TagPrefix="gad" TagName="AlertListControl" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/AlertEditControl.ascx" TagPrefix="gad" TagName="AlertEditControl" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/LetterListControl.ascx" TagPrefix="gad" TagName="LetterListControl" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/ShareListControl.ascx" TagPrefix="gad" TagName="ShareListControl" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderCompany" runat="server">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">



<div id="exTab" class="container" runat="server">   
    <ul id="myTab"  class="nav nav-pills" runat="server">
        <li id="Li1" class="active" runat="server">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="TabLink1" data-toggle="tab" CssClass="alink" runat="server" OnClick="ChangeView">ACTIONARI/ASOCIATI</asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
        <li id="Li2" runat="server">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="TabLink2" data-toggle="tab" CssClass="alink" runat="server" OnClick="ChangeView">DOCUMENTE</asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#3b" data-toggle="tab">Applying clearfix</a>
        </li>
    <li><a href="#4a" data-toggle="tab">Background color</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnTab" runat="server" Value="" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($("#hdnTab").val() != '')
            $('#myTab li').removeClass("active");
        $('#myTab a[id="' + $("#hdnTab").val() + '"]').parent().addClass("active");
        $(".alink").click(function () {
            $("#hdnTab").val($(this).attr("id"))
            __doPostBack($(this).attr("id"), "");
        });
    });


</script>


    <div class="container" >
    <asp:Panel ID="PanelMain" runat="server">
        <asp:MultiView ID="MultiViewMain" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
            <asp:View ID="ViewList" runat="server">
                <gad:ShareholderListControl ID="List" Tag="Shareholder" runat="server"></gad:ShareholderListControl>
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View ID="ViewEdit" runat="server">
                <gad:ShareholderEditControl ID="Edit" Tag="Shareholder" runat="server"></gad:ShareholderEditControl>

           </asp:View>


             <asp:View ID="ViewList_CapitalSubscription" runat="server">
                        <gad:CapitalSubscriptionListControl ID="CapitalSubscriptionListControl" Tag="CapitalSubscription" runat="server" />
                    </asp:View>
             <asp:View ID="ViewEdit_CapitalSubscription" runat="server">
                        <gad:CapitalSubscriptionEditControl ID="CapitalSubscriptionEditControl" Tag="CapitalSubscription" runat="server" />
                   </asp:View>


               <asp:View ID="ViewList_Document" runat="server">
                        <gad:DocumentListControl ID="DocumentListControl" Tag="Document" runat="server" />
                    </asp:View>
               <asp:View ID="ViewEdit_Document" runat="server">
                        <gad:DocumentEditControl ID="DocumentEditControl" Tag="Document" runat="server" />
                   </asp:View>


        </asp:MultiView>

    </asp:Panel>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

Code behind:

```
public void ChangeView(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            LinkButton lnkButton = sender as LinkButton;
            switch (lnkButton.Text) {
                case "ACTIONARI/ASOCIATI": MultiViewMain.SetActiveView(ViewList);
                    break;
                case "DOCUMENTE": MultiViewMain.SetActiveView(ViewList_Document);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

In debug mode, i put breakpoint but my application is not going in my event function...

Comment: Is it inside update panel?

Comment: @AnoopH.N no, it is inside asp:Content

Comment: Since you are using * data-toggle="tab"* the event is not hitting the server side code.

Comment: @Ratheesh, yes, you are right, thank you. Any other workaround to use data-toggle for tabs?

Comment: You can use normal HTML links instead of linkbuttons and can call servers function through Ajax jquery call..

Pls check this link for more reference
https://forums.asp.net/t/2055939.aspx?how+to+call+server+side+code+in+bootstrap+tab+click

Comment: @Ratheesh, i really need to use linkbuttons

Comment: I have added it as an answer. Please check and let me know if you can make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want link buttons to post back you wont be able to get the actual feature of 'nav' functionality. It will definitely post back. In that scenario use the below code

Introduce a hidden field to capture which link you clicked

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnTab" runat="server" Value="" />
```

Then use this script to post back to the server code

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($("#hdnTab").val() != '')
            $('#myTab li').removeClass("active");
        $('#myTab a[id="' + $("#hdnTab").val() + '"]').parent().addClass("active");
        $(".alink").click(function () {
            $("#hdnTab").val($(this).attr("id"))
            __doPostBack($(this).attr("id"), "");
        });
    });
</script>
```

whole HTML

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Control/test.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="test" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Control/Tab2.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="Tab2" %>

<div id="exTab" class="container" runat="server">   
<ul id="myTab"  class="nav nav-pills" runat="server">
    <li id="Li1" class="active" runat="server">
<asp:LinkButton ID="TabLink1" data-toggle="tab" CssClass="alink" runat="server" OnClick="ChangeView">ACTIONARI/ASOCIATI</asp:LinkButton>
    </li>
    <li id="Li2" runat="server">
<asp:LinkButton ID="TabLink2" data-toggle="tab" CssClass="alink" runat="server" OnClick="ChangeView">DOCUMENTE</asp:LinkButton>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#3b" data-toggle="tab">Applying clearfix</a>
    </li>
<li><a href="#4a" data-toggle="tab">Background color</a>
    </li>
</ul> </div><asp:HiddenField ID="hdnTab" runat="server" Value="" /><div class="container" >
<asp:Panel ID="PanelMain" runat="server">
    <asp:MultiView ID="MultiViewMain" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
        <asp:View ID="ViewList" runat="server">
             <uc1:test runat="server" id="test" />
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="ViewEdit" runat="server">
            View Edit
       </asp:View>


         <asp:View ID="ViewList_CapitalSubscription" runat="server">
             ViewList_CapitalSubscription
                </asp:View>
         <asp:View ID="ViewEdit_CapitalSubscription" runat="server">
             ViewEdit_CapitalSubscription
               </asp:View>


           <asp:View ID="ViewList_Document" runat="server">
               ViewList_Document
                </asp:View>
           <asp:View ID="ViewEdit_Document" runat="server">
               <uc1:Tab2 runat="server" id="Tab2" />
               </asp:View>


    </asp:MultiView>

</asp:Panel>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Just updated the answer. I hope you have to add and ID to the UL and add a css class for the Link buttons

Comment: Please provide your html. Are you using Updatepanel?

Comment: put the script after jquery and bootstrap script referece lines

Comment: still not working, when i press at the second tab, it is making postback but it remains at the first tab...

Comment: I have implemented you code with two user controls. it is working fine. Edited my answer

Comment: try my code in a seperate page.. you can see it is working.... you have a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: man, when i press second tab, the first li remain active not the second...

Comment: hi man, no..i need to double click..at one click the first tab remains active, even if it is displaying the view for second tab

Comment: why dont you try "inspect element" and see the "active" class of li of nav-pills are changing?

Comment: yes is changing, but only when i press double click on my li. If a press normall click it wont change...